# Can I make Steam interpret a keyboard key as a controller input?

Tags: steam, controllers, keyboard

I am trying to map a single key on my keyboard to be interpreted as the x-button of my dualshock, but I am not sure how to do it in the steam settings/if I need a program for that.

It's not important for my question, but here is the background to why I am asking, so maybe it gets clearer what I mean:
*I recently found out that in a lot of games steam handles keyboard and conroller button presses seperately, so in a game where you have to mash a button as fast as possible, I can mash the keyboard button and the corresponding controller button to be twice as fast (even if I press them on the same frame it counts as 2 presses). On the other hand having multiple keyboard keys mapped to the same key doesn't have the same effect, so two keyboard presses on the same frame mapped to the same key are counted as just one press.

Since handling both a keyboard and a controller is quite annoying I was wondering if I can't somehow bind one key of my keyboard to be interpreted as being the controller input.*

I hope it is clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: What do you think about using a software that would just press for you ? Something like AutoHotKey for instance ?

Comment: @Fana I have AutoHotkey, but how can I map a key to the dualshock button? I can't just map two keyboard keys to the same key, that's exactly what my workaround solution was, but as explained that is not working

Comment: @Fana I can map a key to a controller button with 'Joy1::Space' for example, but I want it the other way around, however 'Space::Joy1' is not a valid command for AutoHotkey

Comment: Try checking out this page : https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Joystick There's even a script to check if your controller is compatible.

Comment: @Fana I don't see how your link helps. I know that my contrroller is compatible and I know what button corresponds to what label in Autohotkey.

Comment: I've never tried this myself but did you tried using Send, Joy1 or Send, {Joy1 down} ? I'll try to fiddle with this tonight.

Comment: Okay so yeah, AHK cannot send Joystick keys alone. Apparently, you need some kind of Joystick emulator to make it work ... There's a couple of links about that on the AHK forums.

Comment: [Universal Control Remapper](https://github.com/Snoothy/UCR) seems to offer this functionality.